# How to make a background image fill the canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, background

Hello everyone I am new to android and I just have a quick question. I am making an animation using Bitmaps and drawing them to the canvas using the onDraw(). I am trying to draw a background to the canvas that I made in photoshop. I already uploaded it as a drawable and then decoded it to a Bitmap then added it to the onDraw method. It draws, but I doesn't fill the entire canvas like I want it to. Any suggestions and or fixes? Thank you so much, I looked around and saw something about converting the bitmap to an image view but didn't really understand all to well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint)  where the rect for source is the entire bitmap (from 0,0 to width, height) and dest is the entire canvas.  This will stretch the bitmap to fill the canvas.  Be warned this can cause the aspect ratio to be off and/or issues with fuzziness or blockiness.

Comment: OK thanks for the warning and for the help,  I appreciate it!

Comment: Also what values should I add in for the Rect src and RectF dst? thanks again.

Comment: src is (0,0,bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()).   dest is (0,0,canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight())

Comment: oh ok I put canvas.getwidth and height for the src by mistake, thank you once again!